# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Hello  guys I'm working in a project with nestjs and reactjs... when I try to add documet I get this error  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')
multer.config.ts

```
   import { diskStorage } from 'multer';
import * as path from 'path'; // add this line to import the path module

export const multerConfig = {
  dest: './uploads',
  storage: diskStorage({
    destination: './uploads',
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const filename = `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`;
      cb(null, filename);
    },
  }),
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const filetypes = /pdf/;
    const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
    const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
    if (mimetype && extname) {
      return cb(null, true);
    }
    cb(new Error('Only PDF files are allowed'));
  },
};
```

and here service method:

```
  async create(createCandidats: CreateCandidats, user: User): Promise<Candidate> {
    const { email, username, documents } = createCandidats;
    const candidate = new Candidate();
    candidate.email = email;
    candidate.documents = documents;
    candidate.username = username;
    candidate.user = user;
    return await this.candidateRepository.save(candidate);
  }
```

and here the controller part:

```
@Post()
@Roles(Role.Admin)
@UseGuards(AuthGuard())
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('document'))
 async create(
@UploadedFile() document: Express.Multer.File,
@Body() createCandidats: CreateCandidats,
@GetUser() user: User
): Promise<Candidate> {
console.log("check the documents in express multer",document)
console.log('1===>',createCandidats)
const documentName = document.filename;
console.log('2===>',document.filename)
createCandidats.documents = documentName;

return await this.candidateService.create(createCandidats, user);
```

}

I have a method post to post a pdf document in the part of backend it work because when I try to test it with postman in field form data it work but  when i try to test it in the front I get Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')
xhr.js:247 POST http://localhost:3000/candidates 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Where do you do the`.filename`? I don't see it in the react specific code. Are you properly sending a `multipart/form-data` request? Looks like you're sending JSON. I'm making an assumption here that you're using the `FileInterceptor` on the route in the server, is that correct?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yes i think that the problem from react but i think is from the code in the backend i'm using  nestjs .. i'm gonna update my code

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the request to your server as an `application/json`request (previous react side code that was shown). However, you're trying to use the `FileInterceptor` which uses `multer` for parsing the body, so you need to use `multipart/form-data` requests to this endpoint so that the body can be parsed correctly and the file can be added to `req.file` which is what `@UploadedFile()` tells Nest to pass to your route handler.